# SQL statement about average

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

My question is -> 
Retrieve the segment ID and length of each segment that is longer than the average length of all segments. Name the column indicating the length of segments "Length".

Relations:

```
Highway(code, name, startNodeId,endNodeId)

Segment (code, segId, fromKM, toKM) 

City(ZIP,Name)

Node (nodeID, longitude, latitude, type) 

Exit(nodeId, exitNo, ZIP) 

Intersection(nodeId,name) 

HighwayIntersection(code, nodeId,atKm) 

HighwayExit(code, nodeId, atKm)
```

What I got so far is:

```
SELECT code, segid, fromkm, tokm, tokm - fromkm AS Length    
from segment    
GROUP BY segid, tokm-fromkm    
HAVING  AVG( tokm - fromkm) < tokm - fromkm
```

And I got this error message:

> Error:    Your query has syntax errors.
>   Description:  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY
>   expression

Can anyone say what's exactly wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to achieve this:

```
SELECT code, segid, fromkm, tokm, length
FROM
    (
        SELECT code, segid, fromkm, tokm, tokm - fromkm AS Length, AVG(tokm - fromkm) OVER () as AverageLength   
        from segment 
    ) seg
WHERE AverageLength < Length
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the use of window functions ?

Comment: Instead of trying to `group by` a set of columns, which doesn't make sense for your needs, this window function `AVG(tokm - fromkm) OVER ()` is just going to give you the average of that difference for all rows. If you run just the subquery you'll see this computes the same average over and over again for each row. Without the windowing portion `OVER ()` you would need to specify a `group by` and then your average would only be for that `group` which is not desirable. Take a look at Gordon's answer below too, which achieves the same thing with a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 2):

A correlated subquery seems like a reasonable approach:

```
select s.*
from segment s
where s.length > (select avg(s2.length) from segment s2);
```

I *think* this will be a wee bit faster than using window functions, because there is no need to "reassign" the average value on each row.  Both require at least two scans through the data (I'm assuming an index would not be helpful because about half the rows are likely to be returned).